# How do you add a click event to a sub menu item on Excel VBA?

Tags: vba

I have a web page, and on that page there is a menu item. I want to click on a sub menu item. The HTML is:

```
<a href="/apex/COSCaseCreatePage?oMenu=Cases_Submit Case&pagename=COSCaseCreatePage">Submit Case</a>
```

The xpath of element is: `.//*[@id='liSubmitCase']/a`

I want to be able to click on this.

Comment: <a href="/apex/COSCaseCreatePage?oMenu=Cases_Submit Case&pagename=COSCaseCreatePage">Submit Case</a>

Comment: Needs more context - would help to show the code you have so far.

Answer (score 1):

Without additional details it's hard to recommend a better approach. However something like what's written below should work.

```
Sub TestFind()
    Dim Elements As Object
    Dim Element  As Object

    'I'm assuming you already have a pointer
    'to Internet Explorer

    Set Elements = IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("a") ' get all 'a' tags

    For Each Element In Elements
        On Error Resume Next ' you may get an error here
                             ' the object may not have an innertext property
        If Element.InnerText = "Submit Case" Then ' The text you are looking for
            Element.Click ' Click the element
            Exit For ' Exit for loop
        End If
    Next Element

End Sub
```